# How to use Kusto to access Azure Function app code logging() message?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, kql

I have a Python Azure Function that has a bunch of Python `logging.error()/logging.info()` messages. I like this approach (I'm fairly new to Python) as I can look at the run history and see key pieces of information about a run.

**Azure Function run history looks like this:**
[image]

**Example1:**

This Kusto query gets me the **basics** about a given run, but none of the specifics

```
requests
| project timestamp, id, operation_Name, success, resultCode, duration, operation_Id, cloud_RoleName, invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| where timestamp > ago(6d)
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'functionAppName' and operation_Name =~ 'functionName'
| order by timestamp asc
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Example2:**

This query gets me all the details I need, but I have to define the `operation_id` and `InvocationId`

```
union traces
| union exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where operation_Id == '<biglongstring>'
| where customDimensions['InvocationId'] == '<biglongstring1>'
| order by timestamp asc
| project timestamp, message = iff(message != '', message, iff(innermostMessage != '', innermostMessage, customDimensions.['prop__{OriginalFormat}'])), logLevel = customDimensions.['LogLevel']
```

**Output:**

[image]

I need to query specific keywords found in these `logging()` messages.

**How do I do this with a Kusto query?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of the [string search operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatypes-string-operators), such as "has". If your logging message follows a certain convention you can use the [parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator) operator to extract the relevant data into columns.

Comment: What "column" / "attribute" do I reference to get to the actual Azure Function log?

Comment: Answer to my above question was the `message` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Below is what ended up working for me.

`| where message contains "specific string in logging"` was the key. Here `message` has the logging string I was looking for.

```
union traces
| union exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where message contains "specific string in logging"
| order by timestamp asc
| project timestamp, message = iff(message != '', message, iff(innermostMessage != '', innermostMessage, customDimensions.['prop__{OriginalFormat}'])), logLevel = customDimensions.['LogLevel']
```

This one works too:

```
traces
| where message contains "your-string"
```

Comment: Please note that the "has" operator performs much better than "contains"